# SQLCMD command runs in CMD, but not as BAT

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

When in a command prompt, even without admin access, I can run:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS01 –E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='C:\SQLBackups\full\', @backupType='F'"
```

and it runs no problem, but when I try to run it through a batch file, I get the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: 'ûE': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

I have created the script, ran it both with and without admin rights, and have done around 3 hours worth of Googling and haven't been able to find a solution that works.  I have tried various permutations of with and without quotes around assorted parts, and nothing takes.

I am trying to get this to run as a automated script, so I need to make sure that I can just tell Windows to run this and it will go through.

Comment: Why use a `.bat` file at all? `.bat` were designed for command prompt, which has been phased out for years now. Seems like you would be better off create a powershell script (`.ps1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever tool you used to create the batch file changed one of your hyphens:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS01 –E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='C:\SQLBackups\full\', @backupType='F'"
```

If you dump out this line in a hex editor:

```
00000000  65 63 68 6F 20 73 71 6C 63 6D 64 20 2D 53 20 2E  echo sqlcmd -S .
00000010  5C 53 51 4C 45 58 50 52 45 53 53 30 31 20 96 45  \SQLEXPRESS01 .E
00000020  20 2D 51 20 22 45 58 45 43 20 73 70 5F 42 61 63   -Q "EXEC sp_Bac
00000030  6B 75 70 44 61 74 61 62 61 73 65 73 20 40 62 61  kupDatabases @ba
00000040  63 6B 75 70 4C 6F 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 3D 27 43 3A  ckupLocation='C:
00000050  5C 53 51 4C 42 61 63 6B 75 70 73 5C 66 75 6C 6C  \SQLBackups\full
00000060  5C 27 2C 20 40 62 61 63 6B 75 70 54 79 70 65 3D  \', @backupType=
00000070  27 46 27 22 0D 0A                                'F'"..
```

You'll note the character just after `SQLEXPRESS01` isn't a normal hyphen, but character `0x96`.  Change it to a normal hyphen and your script should work.

Comment: Strange, I would never in a million years went to look at this. It was only notepad! Straaaange.  Thank you though!

Comment: Glad to help.  From having suffered a similar fate in the past, this is my first step after getting complaints about oddball characters in error messages from batch files.